# How to get radiobutton by default checked with bootbox prompt

Tags: radio-button, bootbox

I am able to display radio buttons using bootbox prompt. But I am not getting the checked radio button by default. How to do that . Here is my code to displaying radio buttons.

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with a set of Radiobutton inputs!",
    inputType: 'radio',
    inputOptions: [
        {
            text: 'EU Format',
            value: '1',
            checked: true,
        },
        {
            text: 'Standard Format',
            value: '2',
        }
    ],
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
    });
```

I have added `checked: true,` and tried with `checked : "checked"` , but not sure these both not working . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually covered in the documentation, [here](http://bootboxjs.com/documentation.html#prompt-dialog-options). I've also answered this previously, but since I don't have a link to that answer at the moment, this is what you need to do:

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with a set of Radiobutton inputs!",
    inputType: 'radio',
    value: '1', /* value sets the initial checked item */
    inputOptions: [
        {
            text: 'EU Format',
            value: '1',
            checked: true,
        },
        {
            text: 'Standard Format',
            value: '2',
        }
    ],
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

The only difference between radiobuttons and checkboxes is that you can only set a single value with radios. NOTE THAT THE TYPES MUST MATCH. In your example, `'1'` would work, but `1` would not, since the former is a string, whereas the latter is a number. We don't do any explicit type coercion when checking the `value` attribute.

Since you're referencing the radio type, I assume you're using the 5.x version? If so, I have a work-in-progress update to the docs [here](https://tiesont.github.io/bootbox/documentation.html#bb-prompt-dialog), until I can push the 5.x version out. The old docs are still valid, but it (obviously?) doesn't document some of the new features.

Comment: Yes, I am using 5.x and that solves my problem with the example I have shared in question. Thank you.